# How to compare the slope and intercept of two total least squares regressions in R?

Tags: r, comparison, regression

I have a dataset consisting of the two numerical, measured variables D and O, and a third variable that indicates sampling locations (East or West), in total 310 observation.

D and O are linearly correlated, I have used odregress() in R to create total least square regressions. Doing this for both sampling locations seperately leads to [fairly similar regression lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze0Ql.png).
I would like to statistically test if slope and/or intercept are different for these two locations. If I had used a simple linear regression I would use an ANOVA for this. But as far as I know this doesnt work for total least square approaches, is that correct? I have googled a lot but couldnt find any solution to this. Someone suggested bootstrapping both groups separately, getting 100 different slopes and intercepts and then to t.test these slope and intercept groups, but I feel like there should be an easier way of doing this?

I would appreciate any help!

EDIT: Here is the dataset

```
structure(list(O = c(0.7324, 0.78124, 0.78556, 0.78704, 0.81002, 
0.87443, 0.8924, 0.91224, 0.92517, 0.92573, 0.92924, 0.93397, 
0.95854, 0.96477, 0.98186, 0.99257, 0.9931, 0.99488, 0.99901, 
1.0071, 1.0119, 1.0275, 1.0453, 1.0467, 1.0526, 1.0622, 1.0644, 
1.0694, 1.0781, 1.0785, 1.0808, 1.0847, 1.0855, 1.0871, 1.0871, 
1.0872, 1.0935, 1.1028, 1.1067, 1.1106, 1.1207, 1.1251, 1.131, 
1.1359, 1.1359, 1.1387, 1.1419, 1.1496, 1.151, 1.1526, 1.1536, 
1.1538, 1.1592, 1.1595, 1.1645, 1.1705, 1.1766, 1.1842, 1.1997, 
1.2, 1.2011, 1.2077, 1.2085, 1.2175, 1.2183, 1.2287, 1.2301, 
1.2362, 1.2449, 1.248, 1.2508, 1.254, 1.2638, 1.2721, 1.2745, 
1.2858, 1.3039, 1.306, 1.3082, 1.3151, 1.3162, 1.3195, 1.3365, 
1.3392, 1.3413, 1.355, 1.3614, 1.3675, 1.3826, 1.3882, 1.3926, 
1.4075, 1.4094, 1.4109, 1.4155, 1.4414, 1.4487, 1.4554, 1.4642, 
1.4771, 1.4782, 1.4845, 1.5, 1.5136, 1.6112, 1.6173, 1.6228, 
1.6761, 1.7301, 1.7614, 1.8407, 1.893, 2.1033, 2.433, 0.13104, 
0.18361, 0.25999, 0.26253, 0.26939, 0.36762, 0.37335, 0.38632, 
0.39468, 0.48303, 0.50917, 0.5375, 0.54697, 0.55499, 0.55638, 
0.55957, 0.56313, 0.58666, 0.58995, 0.61187, 0.63833, 0.63971, 
0.65251, 0.66876, 0.67105, 0.67192, 0.67333, 0.67489, 0.69292, 
0.69587, 0.71104, 0.71439, 0.715, 0.72289, 0.72526, 0.75811, 
0.75894, 0.76593, 0.76717, 0.77036, 0.7803, 0.78315, 0.78472, 
0.78818, 0.78862, 0.79408, 0.79605, 0.79814, 0.80054, 0.81471, 
0.81491, 0.8154, 0.81859, 0.82125, 0.8259, 0.8261, 0.83919, 0.8415, 
0.84694, 0.85396, 0.86645, 0.86752, 0.86833, 0.87828, 0.88269, 
0.88637, 0.8927, 0.90286, 0.90783, 0.91026, 0.91418, 0.91427, 
0.91478, 0.9166, 0.91863, 0.91865, 0.92676, 0.9295, 0.9334, 0.93429, 
0.93487, 0.93529, 0.94348, 0.95148, 0.952, 0.95354, 0.95403, 
0.9548, 0.96222, 0.96533, 0.96921, 0.97023, 0.97109, 0.97247, 
0.97251, 0.98598, 0.98738, 0.99089, 0.99475, 0.99679, 0.99814, 
1.0051, 1.0061, 1.0074, 1.0097, 1.0189, 1.0231, 1.0305, 1.0379, 
1.0452, 1.0467, 1.0469, 1.0473, 1.0474, 1.0476, 1.0521, 1.06, 
1.0652, 1.0673, 1.0737, 1.0739, 1.0796, 1.0832, 1.0864, 1.0922, 
1.0923, 1.0928, 1.0987, 1.1098, 1.1108, 1.112, 1.119, 1.1319, 
1.135, 1.1355, 1.1368, 1.1406, 1.15, 1.1532, 1.1548, 1.1561, 
1.1563, 1.161, 1.1628, 1.1657, 1.1695, 1.1726, 1.1762, 1.1847, 
1.1851, 1.186, 1.1861, 1.1864, 1.1892, 1.1944, 1.2014, 1.2034, 
1.2035, 1.2088, 1.209, 1.2093, 1.21, 1.226, 1.234, 1.2457, 1.258, 
1.2597, 1.2601, 1.261, 1.2619, 1.2648, 1.2724, 1.2785, 1.3138, 
1.3148, 1.3392, 1.3452, 1.3537, 1.3553, 1.3613, 1.3634, 1.374, 
1.3804, 1.39, 1.3964, 1.4017, 1.4033, 1.4124, 1.454, 1.4909, 
1.4933, 1.5095, 1.6554, 2.2905, 2.2935), D = c(6.7335, 5.9842, 
7.2607, 6.6692, 6.7883, 6.3851, 6.9412, 6.0943, 6.617, 6.3907, 
7.8515, 7.5698, 7.0378, 7.4205, 7.499, 6.8394, 7.0227, 7.5943, 
7.6416, 6.2831, 8.1137, 6.5366, 8.5699, 7.9497, 6.6017, 6.6698, 
7.4538, 8.0064, 7.9721, 8.618, 8.0632, 7.9414, 7.1566, 6.7663, 
8.7359, 6.8296, 7.0741, 7.7438, 6.97, 8.4848, 7.6823, 7.8706, 
7.2941, 7.6861, 7.8883, 7.2856, 7.7869, 7.6533, 8.2157, 8.0779, 
7.4342, 6.9185, 8.6697, 8.1597, 6.869, 7.8173, 8.0279, 7.3248, 
8.1733, 8.8169, 8.1503, 8.6909, 8.7486, 6.9067, 8.4934, 7.891, 
8.5693, 8.9372, 8.5297, 8.1161, 8.1002, 7.764, 7.4613, 8.3119, 
8.1478, 8.0479, 8.0527, 8.6343, 7.8803, 8.032, 7.2934, 7.7577, 
10.055, 6.9696, 8.2901, 9.4509, 8.6809, 8.3964, 9.8273, 8.0222, 
8.933, 8.6679, 9.4189, 9.7793, 9.468, 9.4953, 8.9932, 9.9725, 
9.2968, 9.9642, 9.3904, 8.9943, 8.8995, 9.4839, 9.9091, 9.3051, 
9.8542, 8.5494, 8.5515, 8.287, 10.293, 8.591, 7.8362, 11.147, 
2.8316, 3.8897, 4.5759, 3.7706, 4.225, 4.8624, 3.444, 4.0051, 
4.3401, 2.938, 4.8966, 3.5711, 4.4281, 5.0723, 5.4119, 5.472, 
4.9745, 5.52, 5.5544, 6.9943, 4.8439, 5.0446, 4.5001, 5.1235, 
6.3628, 4.7419, 5.8969, 5.5802, 5.6402, 5.5854, 4.9522, 4.7576, 
4.1654, 5.571, 5.6993, 4.6309, 5.115, 5.5524, 5.6906, 5.7571, 
5.6431, 5.1011, 5.0844, 5.6666, 4.5314, 6.456, 5.1582, 5.3766, 
4.7862, 5.4651, 5.914, 5.345, 5.494, 6.9188, 5.7707, 4.9756, 
5.1671, 6.1472, 5.2446, 6.1542, 5.9616, 5.9502, 5.4772, 6.1042, 
5.7241, 5.592, 4.9474, 6.8122, 7.1245, 6.4829, 5.0722, 6.7933, 
6.2212, 6.2546, 6.434, 6.9884, 6.4172, 5.7726, 5.5066, 5.8896, 
6.9811, 5.0706, 6.2065, 6.6623, 6.0453, 6.6251, 5.7937, 6.889, 
6.4776, 6.3118, 6.2194, 4.9703, 6.4035, 7.5873, 6.4064, 7.1442, 
6.461, 5.4649, 5.3957, 6.7057, 6.4148, 6.52, 5.878, 6.8155, 7.4694, 
6.4654, 6.081, 8.053, 6.5501, 6.6835, 6.8489, 6.2467, 7.4948, 
7.1152, 7.1818, 6.4375, 7.3438, 7.2218, 5.4177, 7.0612, 6.8986, 
6.9722, 6.5899, 6.876, 6.817, 6.9595, 7.674, 6.3334, 6.9009, 
6.236, 7.1216, 6.4549, 6.8034, 6.379, 6.6753, 6.9686, 7.4758, 
7.2485, 6.9605, 6.7682, 6.7202, 7.3145, 7.266, 6.1579, 7.5649, 
7.1079, 7.0922, 6.886, 6.9401, 6.8369, 6.8474, 7.2315, 6.3774, 
5.6486, 7.1576, 7.5174, 7.3115, 7.998, 8.4278, 7.5225, 7.5302, 
7.196, 7.5353, 6.5144, 7.8133, 6.4237, 7.8706, 7.9279, 6.9488, 
7.5694, 7.078, 6.9277, 8.1135, 7.7531, 6.6827, 6.9672, 7.6023, 
8.957, 7.3327, 7.6301, 8.0807, 6.824, 9.4569, 8.8401, 7.1244, 
8.6603, 7.8307, 7.8158, 6.5451, 8.2186, 8.4406, 8.3064, 6.3104, 
7.3834, 7.3139), Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("East", 
"West"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-309L))
```

Comment: Can you please post all of the code you used to fit your models and generate the plot you posted? I'm not getting similar results when I fit models to the data-set you posted.